# Apache (httpd) create a location directive for website homepage

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration, httpd

I want to create a Location/LocationMatch directive in my configuration file to ProxyPass my website homepage "http://www.example.com" without affecting any other Locations and Directories.

I tried `<LocationMatch ^$>` but it did not work at all. How can I create that location if possible?

Thanks,

Comment: Do you mean you want to `ProxyPass` for only homepage (index.x)?

Comment: I want to to make "http://www.example.com" to be proxy passed to other server, currently it is displaying the index.html on the server itself but I want to display the index.html on another cluster of servers.

Comment: Where did you read that `LocationMatch` didn't work inside a `VirtualHost`?  The [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#locationmatch) states that a vhost is a perfectly valid context.  What's the rest of your config look like?  You may be preventing that config from working correctly with some other config.

Comment: @Shane I read that in an old forum post, I was a bit hasty on updating my post. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the below line in your virtual host:

```
ProxyPass /index.html http://another.cluster.server.IP
```

Answer (score 1):

The root of URL space is "/", not "". Try `^/$` instead.

Comment: I tried it didnt work. the root directory handles it instead of my new location